# set_params() for a transformer is not changing the parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to change the 'strategy' for an imputer to "most_frequent" through set_params() and it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
categorical_preprocessing = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('cat_transformer',imputer),('encode',encoder)
])
numerical_preprocessing = Pipeline(steps=
                                   [('numeric_transformer',imputer)]
)

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('cat',categorical_preprocessing,cat_feats),
    ('num',numerical_preprocessing,num_feats)
])

feature_transformer = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=
                                  [
                                      ('pca',pca_transformer),
                                      ('kbest',kbest)
                                  ])

params = {
    'preprocess__cat__cat_transformer__strategy':'most_frequent',
    'preprocess__num__numeric_transformer__strategy':'mean',
}

pipe = Pipeline(
    steps = [('preprocess',preprocessing),
             ('feature_selection',feature_transformer)
    ]
)

pipe = pipe.set_params(**params)
print([pipe.get_params()[key] for key in params.keys()])
```

Output: `['mean', 'mean']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the second value in `params` to `"blatantly wrong"` and you'll spot it.

Your pipeline's `cat_transformer` and `numeric_transformer` are the same object `imputer`.  Setting that object's parameter `strategy` overrides it in both locations in the pipeline.  You should define two separate instances of the imputer.